# Python Divide by 0 Error

Tags: python, calculator

I am currently using this Python code:

```
valid_chars = "0123456789-+/* \n";
while True:
    x = "x="
    y = input(" >> ")
    x += y
    if False in [c in valid_chars for c in y]:
        print("WARNING: Invalid Equation");
        continue;
    if(y == "end"):
        break
    exec(x)
    print(x)
```

It crashes when the user does something like this: 9/0. Error:

```
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

What are some ways that will prevent the user from dividing something by zero?

Comment: So this is Python 3, where `input()` just returns the string the user typed in, and you are trying to use `exec()` to evaluate the expression the user entered?

Your messages should distinguish between the circumstances, otherwise you simply don't know which `print` statement is being executed.

Comment: I fixed that, but thanks for telling me

Comment: The answers are now useless, and this whole thread is useless, and no one reading it in the future can benefit from it because you've taken the issue out of the question. Therefore, anyone who sees this in the future won't be able to know if the question is the same one they have. Please revert the question back to it's earlier state where your issue was more apparent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can except the `ZeroDivisionError` like this

```
x = "1/0"
try:
    exec(x)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
```

If you are using Python 2.x, the input data will be evaluated here itself

```
y = input(" >> ")
```

so, in Python 2.x, you should be using

```
y = raw_input(" >> ")
```

Apart from that, you can improve this piece of code

```
if False in [c in valid_chars for c in y]:
```

like this

```
valid_chars = set("0123456789-+/* \n")    # We make this a set, because
if not all(c in valid_chars for c in y):  # c in valid_chars will be in O(1)
```

As @gnibbler, suggested in the comments section, the same if condition can be written like this

```
if any(c not in valid_chars for c in y):  # c in valid_chars will be in O(1)
```

Another suggestion would be, no need to use semi colons to mark the end of line in Python :)

Comment: `if any(c not in valid_chars for c in y):` is another way of saying it

Comment: @gnibbler Included that as well in the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, but when I add you line of code, it works but renders everything other than an equation that has "/0" useless (This is after I added an "else" command or it would not work at all). When I enter something like "8*8". (this is after I added the "else" command) It would give me: TypeError: exec() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object. Am I missing something? Also, I am using Python 3.3.0.

Comment: @HelloWorld Can you please edit your question and include the updated code?

Comment: @HelloWorld The code works fine for me. Could you please let me know what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I updated it when you were probably away or not looking at this page. Then while you were away, I fixed it. So now it works :D. Thanks!

Comment: @HelloWorld Yup, went to have breakfast. Glad that it works. Cool. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48650/discussion-between-hello-world-and-thefourtheye)

Answer (score 1):

encapsulate your code with a try except

```
try:
  y = input(" >> ")
except Exception as exc:
  # process exception here
```

The reason is the input() is being evaluated as it is read in before y is set. Thus the exception occurs because of the input() and must be caught with the try:
.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that you are executing `exec()` twice. The first time you execute it on the string you have constructed, and this *replaces the value of x* with the result of your entered expression. So the second time you are presumably trying to run `exec(64)`. Look more carefully at the logic flow around `try: ... except: ... else`.

The simplest fix is to start with

```
x = "z="
```

and then print `z` rather than `x`. This should not stop you working to avoid the duplicated execution of your code.

Comment: Yep, I realized that I was executing exec() twice. Fixed it, thanks (just deleted the second exec())!